# How to update Angular 4.2.5 to 4.3.0 or up?

Tags: angular, httpclient

[image]

Hi, I am new to angular 4, stuck with the problem of HttpClient not found in @angular/http OR @angular/common/http.

I am using angular 4.2.5 with asp.net mvc core 2.0.
If "@angular/common/http" is not available in versions prior to 4.3, how do I update my project to use angular version 4.3 or up.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.
**Following is my package.json**

```
        {
      "name": "WebApplication12",
      "private": true,
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
  "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
  "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
  "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
  "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
  "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
  "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
  "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
  "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
  "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
  "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
  "chai": "4.0.2",
  "css": "2.2.1",
  "css-loader": "0.28.4",
  "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
  "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
  "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
  "file-loader": "0.11.2",
  "html-loader": "0.4.5",
  "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
  "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
  "jquery": "3.2.1",
  "json-loader": "0.5.4",
  "karma": "1.7.0",
  "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
  "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
  "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
  "preboot": "4.5.2",
  "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
  "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
  "rxjs": "5.4.2",
  "style-loader": "0.18.2",
  "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
  "typescript": "2.4.1",
  "url-loader": "0.5.9",
  "webpack": "2.5.1",
  "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
  "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
  "zone.js": "0.8.12"
 }
}
```

Comment: The `HttpClient` class is part of the @angular/common/http module. If you cant import it from there, then something must be wrong with your local config. Could you please add some more info about your package.json?

Comment: You need to update your angular dependencies to at least 4.3.0

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, upgrading worked. Thanks